# How to run an app that can't expose port 8080 on AppEngine using a custom flex app

Tags: google-app-engine

Let's say I want to run a docker application on google cloud AppEngine in the flex environment. The docker application is coded to expose port X, but according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) it has to run on port 8080.

Is there a way I can tell AppEngine to use port X instead of 8080. I thought I could use `forwarded_ports`, but I it seems like that doesn't work.

Any suggestions to how this should be done?